# How to read Info.Plist at run-time in react-native iOS app?

Tags: react-native, info.plist

At run time, is there a way to read `CFBundleVersion` from the Info.Plist ?

I want to display the version info in the app's "About Box".

Thanks in advance,

-Ed

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suggest you use this very well done [library](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info)

You'll have all the info you need I think.

**EDIT**

You can also use some Obj-C in your AppDelegate.m file. Just add these lines :

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

NSDictionary *props = @{@"version" : version};
```

and replace these lines :

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"NeedlIOS"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

with these :

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"NeedlIOS"
                                               initialProperties:props
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

You're here passing the version as a prop to you first iOS view. That means that you can get the app version using `this.props.version` in your `index.ios.js` file.

Comment: Thank you, react-native-device-info solved the problem in minutes!  Also thank your for the tip on how to pass props from AppDelegate.m to react-native.  I expect that tip will be useful too!   https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

Comment: Is there a reason why this only works if I run directly from `xcode` ?. The `run-ios` command does not work.

Comment: I can confirm that on React Native 0.48.4 on iOS run-ios does not pass the initialProperties in. I have no idea why either!