# How to get versionCode into react native code (android)

Tags: android, build.gradle, react-native

**Question**

Is it possible to either add things to the default props of the `index.android.js` from the build.gradle or any file at runtime?

OR

Grab the `versionCode` from the `build.gradle` file from within my react-native code?

**Problem**

I'm trying to programmatically have a version number in my application based on the version, build and git sha. The format is essentially `version-gitsha-jenkinsBuildNumber` (for example `1.0.0-abc1234-83`). I was able to get this to work on iOS by using a bash script to add it to the Info.plist and then followed [How to read Info.Plist at run-time in react-native iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640125/how-to-read-info-plist-at-run-time-in-react-native-ios-app) in order to add them to my default props in my `index.ios.js`. I cannot find a way to do this in the `build.gradle`.

**What I've Tried**

Right now, I'm replacing the `versionName` string in the defaultConfig with the git sha using something similar to what I found here: [How to update version number of react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924721/how-to-update-version-number-of-react-native-app)

Then grabbing it inside react native with `react-native-device-info`. I'm also pulling the version number `1.0.0` from the package.json. Lastly I wanted to add the jenkins build number to the `versionCode` of the `defaultConfig` but I have no way of getting it out with `react-native-device-info`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you hack something together using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up running a script at build time that will `cat` the version number and etc into a `version.json` file. Then on runtime, the `.js` file will import that json file and read it from there. It was the least complicated and cleanest way I thought of and it works well!

Comment: I do this as part of my CI workflow. Very simple and easy.