# How to fetch data dynamically from a bundle in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

I am a beginner in ReactNative. I have an app where I am defining the Version number using a Text tag. Is there any way we can get this dynamically through the bundle?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say through bundle, do you mean from your package.json?

If so I would recommend that you use node.js to script your build process, grab the package data from there, and write it to an environment file or a js/ts file you could include in your application and reference to store your version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was suggested to include my data in Info.plist.But I am not sure how can I do that  @Chris

Comment: If using Create React Native App that almost certainly would require you to eject your application or use a third party library. Check out this answer on how to access CFBundleVersion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640125/how-to-read-info-plist-at-run-time-in-react-native-ios-app

Comment: Thanks @Chris ,That is exactly what i was looking for